# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got - ORA-06512:

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have written a simple plsql block and it was executed successfully whenI compile it.

```
 declare

 begin
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT  COLUMN_ID,
        COLUMN_NAME || '' '' || DATA_TYPE || DECODE(DATA_TYPE,''ROWID'','''',''DATE'','''',NULLIF(''('' || DECODE(DATA_TYPE,''NUMBER'',DATA_PRECISION||'',''||DATA_SCALE,DATA_LENGTH) || '')'',''(,)''))  AS COLS
          FROM ALL_TAB_COLS a WHERE OWNER=USER AND TABLE_NAME=''AQ_EVENT_TABLE''';
 end;
 /
```

But,when I try to add implicit cursor then I got this error:

```
[Error] Execution (1: 2): ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

My code is:

```
 declare
 vSQLSlctString varchar2(255);
 begin
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT  COLUMN_ID,
        COLUMN_NAME || '' '' || DATA_TYPE || DECODE(DATA_TYPE,''ROWID'','''',''DATE'','''',NULLIF(''('' || DECODE(DATA_TYPE,''NUMBER'',DATA_PRECISION||'',''||DATA_SCALE,DATA_LENGTH) || '')'',''(,)''))  AS COLS
          FROM ALL_TAB_COLS a WHERE OWNER=USER AND TABLE_NAME=''AQ_EVENT_TABLE''' INTO vSQLSlctString;
 end;
 /
```

Comment: Just a side note. While I don't see the need for dynamic SQL I do see unnecessary double quoting (using two single quotes) in order to generate one in the final result. Since version 10 Oracle has provided an alternative mechanism q'[...]'.   Basically in your query the double quotes reduce to single and the quad quotes ('''') reduce to (''). See the article [quoting string literals](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=311). It is a older article but the content still valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue**: There is multiple `columns` in `selecet` query but `into` clause has only one variable to hold them.

**Resolution**: Number and datatype* of the `columns` in the `select clause` must match with number and datatype of the variables in the `into clause`.

I am considering that your query will return single record as noraml `INTO` will throw error if the `select` query returns more than 1 record.

If you have query that is returning multiple records then you must have to use [bulk collect](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/bulk-processing-with-bulk-collect-and-forall) `into` and some `udt`.

Please use following block.

```
declare
 vcolid number;
 vcoldesc varchar2(4000);
 begin
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT  COLUMN_ID,
        COLUMN_NAME || '' '' || DATA_TYPE || DECODE(DATA_TYPE,''ROWID'','''',''DATE'','''',NULLIF(''('' || DECODE(DATA_TYPE,''NUMBER'',DATA_PRECISION||'',''||DATA_SCALE,DATA_LENGTH) || '')'',''(,)''))  AS COLS
          FROM ALL_TAB_COLS a WHERE OWNER=USER AND TABLE_NAME=''AQ_EVENT_TABLE''' INTO vcolid, vcoldesc;
 end;
 /
```

Now, you can use `vcolid` and `vcoldesc` in any other logic after that `execute immediate`.

Cheers!!

Comment: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 5

Comment: By the way, why you are using dynamic query?